# vba macro fails to create a text file on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to create a text file on the desktop with the name 'Positive.cube'
The text comes from a sheet in ThisWorkbook called 'Positive.LUT'
When I run the vba macro, it creates the new workbook, but fails when it tries to save the new workbook in xlText format. Excel gives
the alert "Positive.cube cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only."

```
Sub save_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Positive LUT").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim fn As String
    fn = "~/Desktop/Positive.cube"
    wb.SaveAs filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlText
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test this, but "~" is usually a shell expansion and not a real file path, hence I would not be astonished if it does not work in a VBA file path. Try Environ("HOME") instead.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the complete (absolute) path? BTW, if you want to copy it to the `ThisWorkbook`'s path, you can probably use `fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Positive.cube`. Also, unless you need the extra worksheet(s), you usually do the following: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Positive LUT").Copy: Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count): Dim fn...`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: I think the OP does clearly *not* want the new file at ThisWorkbook's path, they want it at the users's home directory. And the original copy command looks quite ok to me, this is unlikely to cause the described issue.

Comment: I have been trying all of these suggestions without success. I'm only an occasional Mac user, so I'm not familar with the differences between Excel on Windows and Mac. It turns out that Excel on Mac is saving the text file, but it saves it in a container. 
/Users/john/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/Positive.txt